# Acessar objeto de um método executado por thread em segundo plano em C# com WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, thread, thread-safety

Eu criei uma thread pra executar um processo que demora muito e faz a o processo da aplicação parar por um grande instante

```
private void ExeConsultaClientes()
    {
        thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ExeConsultaClientesst));
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();        
    }
```

O método que o thread executa, é esse:

```
private void ExeConsultaClientesst(){
using (SqlCommand cmd = Program.Conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.WaitCursor;
                string sql = @" *CONSULTA*  ";
                cmd.CommandText = sql;
                DataSet tabela = new DataSet();
                SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);                                       
                adp.Fill(tabela, "Dados");                   
                *GRIDVIEW*.DataSource = tabela;
                *GRIDVIEW*.DataMember = 
                tabela.Tables[0].TableName.ToString();
                *GRIDVIEW*.Refresh();
                Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
                adp.Dispose();
                Program.Conn.Close();
                me.FlushMemory();
                filterColor();
                thread.Suspend();
            }
  }
```

Quando ele vai acessar esses caras

```
CubCadastroPivot.DataSource = tabela;
                CubCadastroPivot.DataMember = tabela.Tables[0].TableName.ToString();
                CubCadastroPivot.Refresh();
                Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
                adp.Dispose();
                Program.Conn.Close();
                me.FlushMemory();
                filterColor();
```

Ele retorna o erro

> Operação entre threads inválida: controle '*GRIDVIEW*' acessado de um thread que não é aquele no qual foi criado.

Há como operar com esses caras que dão erro em um método a parte acessando as variáveis locais do método ExeConsultaClientesst ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o método Invoke, do controle para fazer isso:

```
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
            Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.WaitCursor;
            string sql = @" *CONSULTA*  ";
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            DataSet tabela = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);                                       
            adp.Fill(tabela, "Dados");     
            *GRIDVIEW*.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {

                *GRIDVIEW*.DataSource = tabela.Tables[0];
                *GRIDVIEW*.Refresh();
            });
            Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
            adp.Dispose();
            Program.Conn.Close();
            me.FlushMemory();
            filterColor();
            thread.Suspend();
```

Segundo [a documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/a1hetckb(v=vs.110).aspx), o método `Invoke`:

> Executa o delegado especificado, no thread que tem o identificador da janela subjacente do controle, com a lista de argumentos especificada.

Comment: Corretíssimo meu bom. Já há algum tempo eu vinha tentando aprender, mas não via exemplos válidos pro meu caso. 
Agradecido, abraços !

Comment: por nada! disponha